# How to set Header and Footer with Scrolling Content in Android where footer does not sit above keypad?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-manifest

I am using custom header and footer with scrollable contents in my layout activity. The problem which i am facing is "Footer comes up with keypad when keypad pops up". Also, the background image shrinks. I have to keep footer at the bottom and image stretched even if keypad opens. I tried to set android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" but my header went offscreen when the last edittext was focused. Please help. This is my main layout

### main_layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dashboard">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/header_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    layout="@layout/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout style="@style/linear_layout_inside_scrollview">

        <TextView
            style="@style/text_view_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/large_text"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/line_space"
            android:text="@string/email_check_label" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            style="@style/edit_text_pre_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goToMobileCheck"
            style="@style/pre_login_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/inputs_margin"
            android:onClick="goToMobileCheck"
            android:text="@string/next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding folowing to your **AndroidManifest** in your this activity of ypur layout

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: No...it's not working. Footer is still riding over keypad and background image shrinks.....:(

Comment: may be possible that your layout is not proper otherwise it is working. i would say use Linearlayout and layout-weight in that to generat proper xml file.

Comment: Do you have code for that? I tried Linear Layout also. But issue remains the same....

Answer (score 0):

just use--

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: I tried it also as i have mentioned in my question. But, in this case, the layout pans itself to throw my header out of screen when lower edittexts are focused...